# Does anyone know a siddur containing yotzrot (Ashkenaz or Sefard, preferably in print)?

Tags: prayer-book, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard, yotzrot

In my shul there are some very ancient siddurim containing extended yotzrot for various chagim and shabbatot (e.g. chol hamoed, chanukah, shekalim, parah, hachodesh, hagadol, bereishit, each shabbat from Pesach to Shavuot). I'm trying to buy my own but they seem very hard to come by and all antique. Are there any modern siddurim containing yotzrot?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've got a nearly-200-year-old siddur from Amsterdam, but I don't know of anything approaching the post-war era with those qualifications. The chazzan's edition of Siddur Tefillat Kol Peh has yotzrot for the four parshiot (but nothing else and it's huge).

Comment: מחזור שבחי ישורון

Comment: @DoubleAA, I read the review, but I don't recall, does it have all tefillaus as well?

Comment: http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/ask-the-rabbi/q-a-yotzrot-part-i/2012/02/29/

Comment: http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/ask-the-rabbi/q-a-yotzrot-part-ii/2012/03/07/0/?print

Answer (score 2):

Siddur Tefilla Hashalem -- A. Greenwald

Comment: I can't find this anywhere online - could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The [artscroll siddur](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066509.html) contains yotzrot for shabbat shkalim, zachor, parah, hachodesh and hagadol

Comment: No it doesn't - it contain krovos, and most editions of the artscroll siddur don't even have the full krovos